# Is there any way of activating my script from another account?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to develop an apps script to make copies of certain files in my work account then email them to my personal account. I already have the script to copy and email the files but I need some way of activating it from my personal account. is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of a long shot, but you could do it like this:

You could create a spreadsheet in your personal account.
In that spreadsheet you'll set cell A1 with a value of "0".

Then create a script (for example: "`checkValue`") in your work account that reads that cell (with `sheet.getRange().getValues();` )  and use an `if` statement to trigger the required scripts you want to run if the value changes to "1".

Then create a trigger in your work account to run `checkValue` every 5 minutes.
The next time you change the value to "1" in the spreadsheet of your personal account, the script will executed within 5 minutes.

Comment: Thank you, this will help out a lot.

Comment: You could also create an interface for the app and [publish it as a web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web).  From that you could do this many ways, including a button press on the web app or just /loaded.make it happen when the app is run